# Loading an ico image switches red channel with the blue one

Tags: iphone, icons, uiimage, loading, favicon

This is what I do:
I have a favicon.ico in my resources (for example http://google.com/favicon.ico)

Then I have a UIImageView which loads that image.

```
self.imgTestIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"favicon.ico"];
```

The image showed in the simulator or the in iPhone is the same but with the red color switched with the blue one. Could it be a loading bug from apple?

I also have the same result downloading directly from Internet:

```
self.imgTestIcon.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com/favicon.ico"]]];
```

Thanks David.

Answer (score 2):

I have found this work around:

```
icon = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
icon = [UIImage imageWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(icon)];
```

Basically file is loaded and then converted it to an PNG UIImage, and it works.
Anyway I also used the Libnsbmp library and then some Quartz code to integrate it, it worked fine but I think that the work around runs faster.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it might be a legitimate bug.

You could include an ICO reading library in your app if this is an essential feature ([Libnsbmp](http://www.netsurf-browser.org/projects/libnsbmp/) is one example)

Comment: Thanks, I will see if I can adapt that to my project.

Comment: I have made several tests, and not only the color channels are switched, there are also a lot of problems with the alpha channel information.